# Каков вид сложного предложения?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

Объясните, пожалуйста, к какому виду сложных предложений относится данное? Нужна ли запятая?

*«Сама не знаю, была я замужем(,) или это страшный сон».*

Есть подозрение, что это сложное предложение с бессоюзной и сочинительной связью, намертво лишенное связи подчинительной. Или эта подчинительная связь переживает коварную реинкарнацию?

Comment: Вы уже спрашивали про запятую в предложении. Но перед тем как ставить или не ставить запятые, надо было определить его грамматику.  У Вас же получается наоборот, это можно как-то объяснить? И хорошо бы разобраться с частицей ЛИ, насколько свободно ею можно распоряжаться - оставлять в предложении или убирать из предложения по собственному усмотрению (как известно, отсутствующая в вашем варианте частица ЛИ должна выполнять  роль союза).

Comment: @Jasmin Я про запятую здесь не спрашиваю. Это меня отредактировали.
В полученном ранее ответе о запятой вы мне напоминали правило о сложноподчиненном предложении с союзом "ли… или..." Но части "ли" не было и нет в приведенном мной предложении. Поэтому сомневаюсь, что упомянутое правило применимо в конкретном случае.
Мне кажется, что это сложносочиненное предложение с общей частью, а значит, в нем действует иное правило. Возможно, я ошибаюсь. Хотелось бы узнать мнение знатоков о структуре предложения.

Comment: Мне кажется, что знатоки должны Вам в первую очередь ответить на вопрос о факультативности  или обязательности частицы ЛИ в предложениях со значением изъяснения. С этого надо  начинать грамматический анализ, и от этого зависит постановка запятой. Если ЛИ здесь нужна обязательно , то это союзная подчинительная связь (запятая ставится), а если нет, то мне тоже интересно, как будет определяться вид предложения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*«Сама не знаю, была я замужем или это страшный сон».*

```
Есть подозрение, что это сложное предложение с бессоюзной и 
 сочинительной связью, намертво лишенное связи подчинительной.
```

Не могу поддержать Ваше подозрение, подчинительная связь здесь имеется - смысловая. Вот сочинительной нет точно, потому что предложения никак не равноправные: Сама не знаю(о чём?),была (ли)я замужем или это страшный сон. 2 и 3 простые подчиняются первому (главному).**Сложноподчинённое предложение с двумя придаточными изъяснительными, соединёнными однородно**.  Конструкция разговорная, в таких конструкциях допустим пропуск одного из союзов, особенно повторяющихся. Известно, что ЛИ и ИЛИ - один и тот же союз, просто ЛИ-усечённый, следовательно, разделительный союз ИЛИ выполняет две функции - соединяет два однородных придаточных и указывает на подчинение. Так что это подчинительная конструкция.

Теперь о запятой. При наличии повторяющегося союза запятая ставится в СПП с однородными придаточными, но у нас формально  нет повтора, там материально выражен один союз - сочинительный, следовательно пунктуация такая же, как при однородных членах - без запятой.

Однако союз ИЛИ может иметь и присоединительный характер, следовательно, при желании автор может и запятую  поставить, если придаст последнему предложению присоединительный характер, сделает паузу при чтении.

Comment: Браво! Только что мне почти такой же ответ дали в Грамоте.ру. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=295759 Только там вкратце, а вы все досконально разъяснили.